# Use MagicalRecord with another existing context in RestKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I want to keep using my current RestKit while use MagicRecord for rest of fetches and updates. I want Restkit's MOC send updates to MagicRecord's default context. If I understand right, this is what I am doing. Is this ok?

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore managedObjectContextForCurrentThread];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:[XDBStore storeName]];
[context setParentContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
```

Maybe another way to do it, but still not sure.

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore] persistentStoreCoordinator]; 
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator:coordinator]; 
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_initializeDefaultContextWithCoordinator:coordinator];
```

Anyone had same issue before?

**EDIT 1**

I tried the @casademora's suggestion #1 to set default context, but got this error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlockAndWait: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.'
```

**EDIT 2**

I found a hack. First, open up the setter for default context at magicalrecord. Next, change the concurrency type for RestKit store so its context can be used at magicalrecord.

**NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalRecord.h**

```
+ (void) MR_setDefaultContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;
+ (void) MR_setRootSavingContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
```

**RKManagedObjectStore.m**

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

**Then setup MagicalRecord like this:**

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore managedObjectContextForCurrentThread];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setRootSavingContext:context];

NSManagedObjectContext *defaultContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_newMainQueueContext];
[defaultContext setParentContext:context];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:defaultContext];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an example project available showcasing how to use RestKit with MagicalRecord @ https://github.com/blakewatters/RKMagicalRecord

Answer (score 1):

To summarise Blake's solution

Use a class extension to expose access to MagicalRecord's private setter methods

```
@interface NSManagedObjectContext ()
+ (void)MR_setRootSavingContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (void)MR_setDefaultContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc;
@end
```

Do core data setup first, then this

```
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreCoordinator];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setRootSavingContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1) Get the main context from RestKit, and set that as the default context:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *rkContext = ...; //You'll have to figure this part out
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_setDefaultContext:rkContext];
```

2) For every fetch you do, just specify the context:

```
NSMangedObjectContext *rkContext = ...; //again, I don't know where to get this in restkit
[MyEntity MR_findAllInContext:rkContext];   // <- This will use the RestKit context
```

Comment: how about the methods I used above? Share coordinator?

Comment: BTW, MR_setDefaultContext is private method.

Comment: I tried the 1st one (setting default context), but getting this error. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlockAndWait: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.'